# Why MediaPlayer on lockscreen is not showing?

Tags: android

I have this code:

```
ComponentName cmp = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(),Receiver.class);
am.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(cmp);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setComponent(cmp);
                rc = new RemoteControlClient(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),0,intent,0),Looper.myLooper());
                    am.registerRemoteControlClient(rc);
```

Media button it's working but media player on lockscreen is not showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fix it.

I have in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:targetSdkVersion="11"
```

But remote controls are added in API 15 and i have replaced targetSdkVersion:

```
android:targetSdkVersion="15"
```

And now it's working.